# Google Chrome in Linux Mint

Tags: google-chrome, installation, linux-mint

I am trying to install Google Chrome in Linux Mint. But I am getting error like below.

[image]

Comment: Google Chrome now supports 64-bit systems only.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBay for your reply. My Linux Mint also 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install google chrome , open the terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Upgrading the package to solve the `NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed` error.

Comment: Thanks @GAD3R. Here is your outptut.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjCLN.png

Comment: Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: Thanks @GAD3R for your valuable help. Finally I could browse through Google Chrome after 7 days battle.